# How to make socket server Python run forever

Tags: python, sockets

I have this code create a simple socket server Python.But it closes down each time client disconnect, how to I make it run forever?

```
import socket

HOST = ''
PORT = 8000
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print(data)
            conn.sendall('HelloClient'.encode())
            if not data:
                continue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want run forever just add a `while True` loop and accept the connections inside the loop.

See [here](https://pymotw.com/3/socket/tcp.html) for an example.