# How to create stateful server in python

Tags: python

I am want to make a proxy server that also stateful server and my code only work for one request someone knows how can I make him keep listening until the user close the window or exit ?

```
def film_server(req):
    server_film_ip = "54.71.128.194"
    server_port = 92
    with socket.socket() as sock:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_address = (server_film_ip, server_port)
        sock.connect(server_address)
        sock.send(req.encode())
        ans = sock.recv(1024).decode()
        return ans

def connect_server():
    PORT = 9090
    with socket.socket() as listening_sock:
        listening_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_address = ('', PORT)
        listening_sock.bind(server_address)
        listening_sock.listen(1)
        client_sock, client_address = listening_sock.accept()
        req = client_sock.recv(1024).decode()
        ans = film_server(req)
        client_sock.send(ans.encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need less painful and more high-level abstraction try one of the available [servers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) with help of `serve_forever` method. Your current implementation need endless loop, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50197481/5274713